# Laravel show top 5 jokes based off votes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a question about laravel

I want to show top 5 jokes by votes in laravel. I have a table with jokes and a table with grades. I want to get the average of the grade with a joke id. Then show the top 5 grades. So for instead, a joke can have 5 and 7. This will be a 6 grade.

I tried looking on internet with sadly no luck. I tried different methods but I have had no luck

```
$votes = DB::table('joke_votes')
            ->groupBy('jokes_id')
            ->selectRaw('jokes_id, avg(grade)')
            ->get();
```

I tried this but it didnt work

I want the system to find all the grades by a joke. Calculate the average grade and show the top 5 of it.

These are the tables:

joke_votes:
[image]

jokes: 
[image]

Comment: You want top 5 jokes, it means there is a chance, there will be 5 jokes with top grade/votes right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try the below code,

```
$votes = DB::table('joke_votes')
        ->selectRaw('jokes_id, avg(grade) as avgGrade')
        ->groupBy('jokes_id')
        ->orderBy('avgGrade', 'desc')
        ->limit(5)
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want the system to find all the grades by a joke. Calculate the
>   average grade and show the top 5 of it.

The general SQL queries would be more or less like, assuming you want to fetch the jokes based on the AVG grade.

```
SELECT 
 jokes.*
FROM (
 SELECT 
    joke_votes.joke_id
  , AVG(joke_votes.grade) AS avg_grade
 FROM 
  joke_votes
 GROUP BY  
  joke_votes.joke_id

) AS joke_votes__avg_grade
INNER JOIN 
 jokes
ON
 joke_votes__avg_grade.joke_id = jokes.id
ORDER BY 
  joke_votes__avg_grade.avg_grade DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Or

```
SELECT 
 jokes.*
FROM (
 SELECT 
    joke_votes.joke_id
  , AVG(joke_votes.grade) AS avg_grade
 FROM 
  joke_votes
 GROUP BY  
  joke_votes.joke_id
 ORDER BY 
  joke_votes.avg_grade DESC
 LIMIT 5    
) AS joke_votes__avg_grade
INNER JOIN 
 jokes
ON
 joke_votes__avg_grade.joke_id = jokes.id
ORDER BY 
 joke_votes.avg_grade DESC
```

Don't ask me how to do this in Laraval, but pretty sure you can use deliverd tables (subqueries) in joins in Laraval.
When i look into the [manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins) section **Sub-Query Joins**